# Gives error 422 When I try to submit the form Rocket Rust

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I'm trying to make a form to create posts(I'm not acessing db yet) in Rocket Rust.
When I try to submit the form I get error 422.

Error:

```
POST /new_post application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
    => Matched: POST /new_post (new_post_form)
    => Error: The incoming form failed to parse.
    => Outcome: Failure
    => Warning: Responding with 422 Unprocessable Entity catcher.
    => Response succeeded.
```

Handler code:

```
#[post("/new_post", data="<form>")]
fn new_post_form(form: Form<NewPostForm>) -> Flash<Redirect>  {
    let form = form.into_inner();
    if form.body.is_empty() {
        Flash::error(Redirect::to("/new_post"), "NoBodyError");
    }
    if form.name.is_empty() {
        Flash::error(Redirect::to("/new_post"), "NoNameError");
    }
    if form.name.is_empty() && form.body.is_empty() {
        Flash::error(Redirect::to("/new_post"), "NoNameBodyError")
    } else {
        Flash::error(Redirect::to("/new_post"), "NoNameBodyError")
    }
}
```

Form struct:

```
#[derive(FromForm)]
pub struct NewPostForm {
    pub name: String,
    pub body: String
}
```

HTML Form:

```
<form action="/new_post" method="post">
  name:<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
  Body:<input type="text" name="body" id="body">
  <button type="submit" name="button"></button>
</form>
```

P.S. I think that the problem is in HTML Form, not in Rust. If the problem was in Rust, It would give another error.

Comment: Please include your handler code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to understand what exactly is the problem here from just the code snippets. I think you should try to see what exact data is received by your backend and try to get insight why it is not parsed by the codegen'ed `FromForm` implementation.

You can actually implement the `FromForm` trait yourself. Just remove `#[derive(FromForm)]` and do:

```
impl<'f> FromForm<'f> for NewPostForm {
    type Error = ();

    fn from_form(items: &mut FormItems<'f>, strict: bool) -> Result<NewPostForm, ()> {
        // Inspect `items` here
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I have solved the problem by using LeitnentForm instead of Form. Only will I get data using Leinent form?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in HTML form. When I removed `name="button"`, The Form start working.

Updated Form:

```
<form action="/new_post" method="post">
  name:<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
  Body:<input type="text" name="body" id="body">
  <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```